# Make clean URLS and retrieve query string

Tags: php, apache, seo, sitemap

Is there a way to insert relative URLS in php code such as `/forums/(forumID)/` into  tags while setting up my site? Then when I am trying to get which forumID the current page is, to get it via a `$_GET` request without using a template system like Smarty, CakePHP etc or Apache rewrite module? Or is it a huge headache? I just want to be able to not be bound to one web server type (Apache).

Comment: So you worry about bounding to web-server, but don't worry about bounding to used programming language? Isn't that weird? ;-)

Comment: I've got no idea how Smarty would factor into this, but you need to setup Apache, Nginx, or similar to handle the URL

Comment: @zerkms Well the reason I say that is b/c I am mainly building classes right now that can be used with almost any website I build. So if someone wants me to build a website but they already have a certain setup etc, but just want to add a website to it, but they don't use apache, then Im still good to go.

Comment: @adlawson Well I know template systems like smarty, cakephp, etc have that kind of functionality that is built into the system.

Comment: The simple fact is that PHP isn't aware of the request until the webserver routes the request to it. To have a URL like that, you need Apache Mod_Rewrite or equivalent to read the request and route it to a front controller (index.php). Even the popular distributed CMS systems (Wordpress, Magento, Drupal etc) require this setup.

Comment: @adlawson Hmm.. Im confused though, b/c I know frameworks like Django, CakePHP, etc have it built into the framework no matter which server type you use. So I thought there was a way to do it via regex match or something. Im pretty much a novice when it comes to how data is really transferred back and forth though. Ive mainly just done PHP, ASP.NET, and python programming

Comment: @adlawson Oh nm about Django.. I just remembered those pages are all defined by functions. So thats totally different. LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... carried on from OP comments.

These frameworks read the request again in their respective languages to allow the framework to route to specific controllers, but they still need the webserver to be setup to send the request to the framework in the first place.

- Client requests http://example.com/forums/123
- After DNS lookup, request hits server at 127.0.0.1:80
- Webserver (eg Apache) listens for port 80 and accepts request
- Apache routes request to server-side script

This is the journey as the web server sees it. It needs to read the request before it even hits the server-side scripting language (PHP/Python/Ruby etc).

The server-side languages can then re-read the URL once the webserver has hit the front controller as they please.

Comment: Thanks guys for your input. Like I said Im definitely a novice at server setups etc and how data is transferred. Im just trying to make some general classes in PHP that I can use for building websites on the side for extra money while in college. Thanks for clearing this up for me everyone!! :)

Answer (score 4):

Clean urls are fairly easy to do, but if the web pages are vastly different, it may cause some problems.

You'll need to edit your .htaccess file and add something similar to this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1
#This will process http://example.com/forum as http://example.com/index.php?page=forum

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
#This includes the trailing slash

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2
#This will process http://example.com/forum/512 as http://example.com/index.php?page=forum&id=512
```

This is a good source for more information http://www.desiquintans.com/cleanurls

Comment: He doesn't want it tied to a server setup, so this is a no go.

Answer (score 1):

**The main reasons to have clean urls from an architecture point of view:**

- **They are not tied to any programming language.** If you have `.php` or any other extensions, you'd have to set up your server to accept `.php` extensions for other languages if you switch to ASP.net.
- **They are are easy to route in any language or server setup.** All modern servers I know of have modules to route urls.

Note that to use a programming language to route the urls, you still have to set up your server to direct everything to a bootstrap file.  Honestly, you are not getting around server configurations of some kind no matter what.

**Conclusion: your logic for wanting your project set up this way will not work without doing *some* server setup.**